# GNU gcc and g++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, gnu

Are the gcc and g++ compilers installed on a MAC OS X machine different from the ones on Ubuntu (Linux) GNU gcc and g++ compilers?

I am using Eclipse to develop a C++ program and there is toolchain section where it says MacOSX GCC and I was wondering if I need to install another compiler so that the executable would also run on Linux machines.

<sub>I am a bit new to the technical details of C++ development so I am sorry if this question does not make sense.</sub>

Comment: Even if your version of gcc is the same as Ubuntu, the program it outputs is different. For one, Linux programs use the ELF executable format, macs don't (I don't remember what they use, a google search should tell you). What you're describing is called cross compiling, and even then a single binary will rarely run on both platforms (you'd need to compile a separate program for each).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It it very unlikely that binary will execute on both Mac and on Linux. If is pretty likely that a binary will not execute between different distro's of Linux. You can either compile you binary for each OS. Or you can distribute the source code for you application and let you users compile it themselves.

Different versions of libstdc++.so are likely distributed with different OS's and this will cause you problems. A solution that partly works is to statically compile your binary so you are not depending on the target systems installed version of libraries.

Comment: Is it possible that the modifications I make on a mac to a code originally developed on a linux platform will cause problems when the code is attempted to be compiled on a linux platform after the changes? I mean, I see that the binaries are fragile between different platforms but what about the the actual source code?

Comment: Very very much so. This is why writing portable code is hard. If you stick to pure ANSI C or C++ your code should compile on any platform without issue. But there are certain gotchya's for example Endian ordering, default values for say max filename lengths, size of certain types. Once you learn the difference you usually cope with them with #if WINDOW do this #elif MAC do this #elif WEIRD_OS do the #endif As an example in a past job we support 8 different OS's and 4 major (and ever minor inbetween) version of our software. Effectively we were support over 300 different version of our code :-)

Comment: Also on Mac OS you can create universal binaries, which may contain 32-bit and 64-bit code at the same time, even targeting different processors. Not so in Linux. You can realistically achieve source compatibility, but not binary. The same code usually compiles on Mac and Linux, with few differences, especially if you only target x86 and have no GUI. But you do have to compile it for the different platforms, often even for different distros. If you build on a recent Ubuntu, your binary won't run on older distros. Static linking may help with executables, but not with shared objects.

Comment: @Cemre: Mac file names are typically not case sensitive, on Linux they are. So be careful with those #includes. Some functions exist on Linux but not on the Mac, like clock_gettime or wcscasecmp (Xcode 4 might be better with this). I make very minor fixes between Linux and Mac, they're almost the same, for my purposes at least. Windows is a different story. A lot of the functions I thought were standard C are actually Microsoft-specific. One example: stricmp vs strcasecmp. My project doesn't have a GUI BTW, and it's ANSI C and C++, no Objective C either.

Answer (score 0):

MacOS is not Linux, it might have a bit in common with BSD, but definitely not Linux. They do, or can, use different configurations of the same compiler, but the programs are not compatible.

The only way you're going to run the same program on both is if you have something like Wine to provide a compatibility layer.